# Convergence in distribution (with measurable functions)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, measurable-functions, polish-spaces

*The definition of convergence in distribution:*

Let $S$ be a seperable metric space and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a $S$-valued sequence of random variables. Then $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge in distribution to a $S$-valued random variable $X$ if

$(*) \ \mathbf{E}[f(X_n)]=\mathbf{E}[f(X)]$

for all continuous, bounded functions $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$.

**My question:** In my case is $S$ a polish space. I have shown $(*)$ for all measurable, bounded functions $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$. Is this enough for convergence in distribution?

Comment: My question is exactly the opposite: I showed $(*)$ for all measurable, bounded functions. Is it then enough for convergence in distribution, if $S$ is a polish space?

Comment: My comment should have been the opposite too : Obviously, if you have (∗) for all measurable functions, you'll have the result for all continuous functions...

Comment: Thank you very much. But why follows the result for all continous functions?

Comment: continuous functions are measurable.